# Is this SQL query possible? I am trying to get the least frequent names in this table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

This is a toy public table in google BigQuery:
The table contains the names given to people in the US at birth and the frequency of those names for each state and year from 1910 to 2020
Columns: name, year, state, number, gender
[names toy table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSBcH.png)

I am trying to get the LEAST popular names (names with lowest 'number' column) each year.

I am not sure this is possible with this schema.

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want to handle a tie, you want [rank or row_number](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/numbering_functions).

```
select 
    *
from (
    select 
        *,
        row_number() over (partition by year order by name_frequency) as rn
    from (
        select
            year,
            name,
            sum(number) as name_frequency
        from `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_2013`
        group by
            year,
            name     
        ) sub1
    ) sub2
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach

```
select * from (
  select year, gender, name, sum(number) number
  from `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_2013`
  group by year, gender, name
  qualify 1 = row_number() over(partition by year, gender order by number)
)
pivot (any_value(name) name, any_value(number) number for gender in ('M', 'F'))
# order by year desc
```

with output (just top 9 shown)

[image]

In reality - there are many names that have same least frequency - to get all of them - use below approach

```
select * from (
  select year, gender, name, sum(number) number
  from `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_2013`
  group by year, gender, name
  qualify 1 = dense_rank() over(partition by year, gender order by number)
)
pivot (string_agg(name) name, any_value(number) number for gender in ('M', 'F'))
```

with output

[image]

while if you would look for most frequent - you would use below

```
select * from (
  select year, gender, name, sum(number) number
  from `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_2013`
  group by year, gender, name
  qualify 1 = dense_rank() over(partition by year, gender order by number desc)
)
pivot (string_agg(name) name, any_value(number) number for gender in ('M', 'F'))
```

with just one most frequent name per year/gender

[image]